# Как добавить базу данных sqlite в файл ресурсов?

Tags: python, sqlite, qrc

У меня есть база данных `database.db`

Есть модуль `data_base.py`
Вот его содержимое:

```
import sqlite3 as sql
import resource


def database_creation():  # Создание таблицы users в базе данных
    con = sql.connect(base)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users(
            id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
            name TEXT,
            password TEXT,
            calories INT,
            protein INT,
            fats INT,
            carbohydrates INT
            );
        """)
    con.commit()


def get_list_name_user():  # Получает список имен из базы
    con = sql.connect(base)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM users;")
    name_users_result = cur.fetchall()
    list_name_users = []
    for i in name_users_result:
        list_name_users.append(*i)
    con.close()
    return list_name_users


def set_add_base_person(lst):  # Добавляет нового пользователя
    con = sql.connect(base)
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO users (name, password, calories, protein, fats, "
                "carbohydrates) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);", lst)
    con.commit()
    con.close()


base = ":/database.db"
list_users_data = ['женя', '43434334', 333, 44, 44, 55]
database_creation()
```

Есть файл ресурсов `resource.qrc`
Вот его содержимое:

```
<RCC>
  <qresource prefix="/">
    <file>database.db</file>
  </qresource>
</RCC>
```

С помощью команды `pyrcc5 -o resource.py resource.qrc` Я создаю файл ресурсов

Когда я обращаюсь к базе данных с помощью префикса которой прописал в фале ресурсов он выдает мне ошибку

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если я прописываю полный путь к базе в переменной `base`, то все работает

Comment: Tesla, объясните пожалуйста лучше, что вы хотите сделать и для чего вам это надо и как вы с этой БД. находящейся в файле ресурсов, собираетесь работать.

Comment: Возможно я не правильно поставил вопрос, я имею ввиду как лучше собирать проект с бд?